# C3 chart width changes on show/hide

Tags: ember.js, toggle, show-hide, c3.js

I am working on an ember project and using C3 charts in that for data visualisation . 
On one page I have a requirement to put 2 charts and need to do show/hide on button click(toggle effect). But on toggling the second chart(initially hidden) , the width of chart gets changed(increased ) , but first chart(initially shown) stays as expected.

One more thing that I noticed , is that if I open the console to debug , that second chart comes back to its original width. It's very strange , not able to understand this behaviour .

If someone have any idea about this issue. Kindly share ...

Comment: is it possible for you to provide your code or even a simple twiddle to illustrate the case?

Answer (score 1):

> One more thing that I noticed , is that if I open the console to debug , that second chart comes back to its original width. It's very strange , not able to understand this behaviour

I suspect that C3 uses `resize` event to adjust chart size. I don't know what technique do you use to show/hide, but firing `resize` event manually after few milliseconds may help in this case. But if you use handlebar's `{{if}}` helper to show/hide chart and component to render c3, there shouldn't be such issue at all.